# Google tasks update error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am attempting to update a task with the following code:

```
function updtsk(task,id)
{
  var url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/tasks/v1/lists/@default/tasks/'+id;
  var req = {
    'method': 'PUT',
    'headers': {
      'Content-type': 'application/json'
    },
    'body': JSON.stringify(task)
  };
  var addDone = function(resp, xhr) {
    if (xhr.status != 200) {
      notifyFailure('Couldn\'t update task.', xhr.status);
      return;
    }

    //notifySuccess(task['title']);
  }

  oauth.sendSignedRequest(url, addDone, req);
}
```

I get the following error however:

```
"{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalid",
    "message": "Invalid Value"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Invalid Value"
 }
}
"
```

The update body is this:

```
{
 'title': $(this).val()
};
```

I am using the chrome_ex_oauth api and could use some help.

Comment: Can you post an example of an update body that is being sent which results in this error being returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible you need to include additional fields in the update.

The documentation here: http://code.google.com/apis/tasks/v1/reference.html#resource_tasks appears to indicate the *status* property is not optional (the other mutable fields are listed as optional in their descriptions).  You may also need to include the *kind* property with the static value indicated there.

Answer (score 12):

Try passing the 'id' key/value pair together with the title information you are already sending.

I had this same problem, even using the API explorer.  There's no documentation to indicate this is a required parameter, especially since it is included in the URL.  Once I added id, it worked properly.

Comment: Does http body must contain json serialized task resource?

Comment: So Google requires the `id` of the task to be passed as a part of url, parameters and body (Task resource)

Answer (score 0):

In Google Task API for updating any TaskList Task:
First we have to get task with use of TaskList Id and Task Id
Second step change/update in task and again update that task.
Hope this is helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

I read these answers several times, but only saw what I thought I already knew, which was wrong. The documentation for insert/update/etc. states

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/tasks/v1/lists/tasklist/tasks
```

It is the *id* of the ***tasklist*** being modified (e.g. something like "MTA1MjEpoqwdNTMzMjAzo349YDA6MDow") and not the *title* of the ***tasklist*** e.g. "My Task List" that needs to be passed in the POST request header, e.g.

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/tasks/v1/lists/MTA1MjEpoqwdNTMzMjAzo349YDA6MDow/tasks
```

You can find the id of the list by doing a tasklists 'list' query.

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/tasks/v1/users/@me/lists
```

which returns, e.g. something like this:

```
{
   "kind": "tasks#taskList",
   "id": "MTA1MjEpoqwdNTMzMjAzo349YDA6MDow",
   "title": "My Task List",
   "updated": "2019-03-15T21:21:03.000Z",
   "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/tasks/v1/users/@me/lists/MTA1MjE0Njc5NTMzMjA1NDk0NDA6MDM1NDgwMjIxODgyMjcyODow"
  }
```

You can see the tasklist id in the response, which can then be used in the POST to modify the desired tasklist.
Answers to this question have been posted, but none with explicit examples. Hopefully this example will help someone get past this newbie kind of problem.