# Setting id to task using Google Task API returns 400 invalid value

Tags: google-tasks-api, google-tasks

I am using Google's Java API for an project.

Strangely, inserting a task without setting an id works fine. However, inserting a task with a id returns a 400 invalid value error. The id is to be used for syncing local data with Google Tasks

I'm pretty sure there's nothing wrong with the algorithm that generates the ids for the task. The same algorithm works perfectly for Google Calendar API.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

You may refer with this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8674004/5832311). It suggested to pass the [`id`](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/tasks/v1/reference/tasks) key/value pair together with the title information you are already sending. There's no documentation to indicate this is a required parameter, especially since it is included in the URL. Google requires the `id` of the task to be passed as a part of url, parameters and body.