# Specify Google Task ID on insert

Tags: google-tasks-api

I am working with Google Tasks, using the PHP library:
https://developers.google.com/tasks/v1/reference/tasks

I am trying to insert a task with a custom ID.

I found this topic:
[Setting id to task using Google Task API returns 400 invalid value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43172432/setting-id-to-task-using-google-task-api-returns-400-invalid-value)

which points to this topic:
[Google tasks update error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6404725/google-tasks-update-error/8674004#8674004)

They suggest to send the Task ID with the Task title. I think I have done that.

This is the code info from the Google API reference

```
$task = new Task();
$task->setTitle('New Task');
$task->setNotes('Please complete me');
$task->setDue(new TaskDateTime('2010-10-15T12:00:00.000Z'));

$result = $service->insertTasks('@default', $task);
echo $result->getId();
```

This is my code, I got setID() from the library itself.

```
$taskNew = new Google_Service_Tasks_Task();
$taskNew->setId('2013');
$taskNew->setTitle('Notify');
$taskNew->setDue(new TaskDateTime('2018-10-27T00:00:00.000Z'));

$results3 = $service->tasks->insert('.....', $taskNew);
```

I keep getting an error and it refuses to make the task.

Using this API tool:
https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/tasks/v1/tasks.tasks.insert

I can insert tasks successfully, so long as the system makes the ID. The Google Task API will insert the task, but assign its own ID.
If I specify a custom ID, then I get a 400 error "Invalid value".

I am making tasks to correspond to events saved in my program's database. I need to be able to find the task that matches a database event when I need to make changes to the due date or completed.
The reason I want to set my own ID, is so I can find the specific task and make changes.

I could add a new field to the database with the ID that google generates. But I would prefer to not have to change the database and the rest of the program as well.

Thanks so much for any help,
- Jon

Comment: Is it ever possible to have two or more tasks associated with the same db entry? If so, then a table associating your db row IDs with the relevant Google task ID is the best solution. This won't change anything about how other parts use the source db rows.

Answer (score 0):

Task Id is the read-only parameter. 
I solved this question by using a prefix for the task`s Title. 
For example: "[my_id] Task Title".